# Using General Mixed Effects models to address pseudo replication

Tags: r, regression, logistic, mixed-model, glmm

A common problem in animal studies is pseudoreplication of data points due to a limit in the number of animals available in a study population.

I need to address any pseudoreplication and influence of individual in my study. I had planned to model ID (individual animal) as a random factor in a glmr.

In my main study, with a large data set I am using permutation based logistic regressions for whether animals of a certain age class are underweight. Looking at a model :

```
mod1 <- glm(Underweight ~ Age.Class, family = binomial(), data = data)
```

against (likelihood ratio test) a permuted data set of the same data, this finds Age class predicts tendency to be underweight.

To factor in ID into this, I assign individual identity to a subset of my data (was not possible time wise to ID whole data set) I had planned to address pseudo replication as a post hoc assessment on the work with this subset of data.

I am confused as to the method for this, would I:

a) do a simple LRT test between a model that factors in ID and doesn't, if there is no sig difference then ID has no effect, i.e.:

```
glm1 <-  glmer(Underweight ~ Age.Class + (1 | ID.number), 
               family = binomial(), data = data)

glm2 <-  glmer(Underweight ~ Age.Class, 
               family = binomial(), data = data)


lrtest(glm1, glm2)
```

Or

b) Do I also need to interpret ID into some kind of permutation test like the original model?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

- It is not clear why you want to use permutation tests and not the classic $\chi^2$ distribution for the likelihood ratio test.
- Model `glm2` uses `glmer()` but *without* including any random effects. Does this really work? You should better compare using `anova()` model `mod1` the logistic regression without random effects (null hypothesis) with model `glm1` that includes the random intercepts (alternative hypothesis).